# secondary x axis at an offset

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to have 2 axes in a matplotlib figure. The snippet to create the secondary axis and plot everything reads:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4.5, 4), dpi=100)
#... main code ...
ax.set_xlabel("Time (EST)")
ax2 = ax.secondary_xaxis('bottom')
ax2.set_xticks(x_diebus)
ax2.set_xticklabels(diebus_24)
ax.set_xticks(x_12)
ax.set_xticklabels(label_12)
ax.set_ylabel(r'Y label')
ax.set_title("Title")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('figure1.png')
```

The problem is that both the primary and secondary axes superimpose:
[image]

Note: When I switched the secondary axis with `ax2 = ax.secondary_xaxis('top')`, it worked fine with the primary axis at the bottom and the secondary at the top.

Comment: What's the question? You asked Matplotlib to put the secondary axis at the bottom and it did that.

Comment: The question is how to put the secondary axis at the bottom without overlapping the primary axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_xaxis.html#), you can use a `float` instead of a string for the axes placement.

> location{'top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right'} or float
>
> The position to put the secondary axis. Strings can be 'top' or 'bottom' for orientation='x' and 'right' or 'left' for orientation='y'. A float indicates the relative position on the parent axes to put the new axes, 0.0 being the bottom (or left) and 1.0 being the top (or right).

Since we want the axis to be placed below the bottom one, we will use a negative `float`.

Here's an example of its usage. You may need to adjust the float value for your specific case. Also, I recommend using the `functions` `kwarg` to set the mapping rather than setting the ticks manually as you do.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 6])
ax2 = ax.secondary_xaxis(-0.2, functions=(lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**0.5))
ax.set_xlabel("axis 1")
ax2.set_xlabel("axis 2")
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]